# WiX - Passing parameters to a CustomAction (DLL)

Tags: installation, parameters, wix, custom-action

I've got a DLL from an old WiSE installer that i'm trying to get working in WiX, so i'm pretty sure the DLL works with MSI-based installers.

Here is my definition:

```
<Binary Id="SetupDLL" SourceFile="../Tools/Setup.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="ReadConfigFiles" BinaryKey="SetupDLL" DllEntry="readConfigFiles" />
```

and usage:

```
<Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="ReadConfigFiles" Order="3">1</Publish>
```

My C++ function looks like this:

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall ReadConfigFiles(MSIHANDLE hInstall, CHAR * szDirectory)
```

Where exactly can I pass in parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass parameters directly because in order for this to work, your function has to be exported with exactly the right footprint.  When you call `readConfigFiles` in your custom action dll, it should have a footprint like this:

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall readConfigFiles(MSIHANDLE hInstaller);
```

You can use the `hInstaller` parameter to read properties from the MSI.  Use `MsiGetProperty()`:

```
HRESULT GetProperty(MSIHANDLE hInstaller, LPCWSTR property, LPWSTR value, DWORD cch_value) {
    UINT err = MsiGetProperty(hInstaller, property, value, &cch_value);
    return (err == ERROR_SUCCESS ? S_OK : E_FAIL);
}
```

Then just make sure you set the property in your .wxs file:

```
<Property Id="YOUR-PROPERTY-NAME">your-property-value</Property>
```

Comment: &cch_value is buffer length (in case someone else is wondering, i had to dig a bit to find this out ;)

There's a few more in-depth examples out there but a "trick" i found if you don't know length is to call MsiGetProperty with bufferLen = 0, which fails because there isn't enough space to store a value but it also fills bufferLen with how much space is needed to store the actual value. Calling MsiGetProperty again (making sure to allocate value = TCHAR[bufferLen+1] with +1 to make room for a null-terminator) will return the actual value.

Comment: Yeah, cch is Microsoft's Hungarian notation for "Count of CHaracters", as opposed to cb which is "Count of Bytes".

Comment: And yes, that's a [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134(v=vs.85).aspx).  Win32 and the shell were pretty consistent in following this pattern.